# Is resume() function available in python 2.7?

Tags: python, sockets, python-2.7

Is there any `resume()` function in python. I need to apply it on my program. need proper explanation I searched a lot but didn't get it.

Here is my code where I need to place the `resume` function.

```
try:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
    abc  =  soup.find('div', attrs={})
    link =    abc.find('a')['href']
    #result is dictionary
    results['Link'] =  "http://{0}".format(link)
    print results
    #pause.minute(1)
    #time.sleep(10)

except Exception:
    print "socket error continuing the process"
    time.sleep(4)
    #pause.minute(1)
    #break
```

I apply `pause`, `time.stamp` and `break` but not getting the required result. If any error appears in `try` then I want to `pause` the program. `try` block is already inside loop.

Comment: Please explain what a `resume()` function is supposed to do.

Comment: im collecting the url from website im getting socket error so i used try and catch for this so in try if program stuck any where so i need to resume from the same position so i need to know how i can do this in python.

Comment: You'll need to show some code and your error so that people have a chance of helping you... As it stands, this is far too vague for anyone to provide an answer.

Comment: Python's exceptions cannot be resumed once raised (the same as with e.g. Java and C++ exceptions). If you want to resume operation after the exception, you will need a try/except block, *and* an explicit loop around the code that generates the exception.

Comment: I have shown my work above.

Comment: try is inside loop now i need to know how i can apply the resume code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resume the code in case of an exception, put it inside a loop:

```
import time
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup # $ pip install beautifulsoup4

for _ in range(max_retries):
   try:
       r = urllib2.urlopen(url) 
       encoding = r.info().getparam('charset')
       html = r.read()
   except Exception as e:
       last_error = e
       time.sleep(retry_timeout)
   else:
       break
else: # all max_retries attempts failed 
   raise last_error 

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, from_encoding=encoding)
# ...
```