# iterate the list in python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, web, web-scraping

I have a loop inside loop i'm using try n catch once get error try n catch works fine but loop continues to next value.  What I need is that where the loop breaks start from the same value don't continue to next so how i can do that with my code [like in other languages: in c++, it is i--]

```
for 
r = urllib2.urlopen(url) 
       encoding = r.info().getparam('charset')
       html = r.read()
c = td.find('a')['href']
urls = []
urls.append(c)
#collecting urls from first page then from those url collecting further info in below loop

    for abc in urls:
       try:
           r = urllib2.urlopen(abc) 
           encoding = r.info().getparam('charset')
           html = r.read()
       except Exception as e:
           last_error = e
           time.sleep(retry_timeout) #here is the problem once get error then switch from next value
```

I need a more pythonic way to do this.
Waiting for a reply. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please only use version numbers where it is known that a problem is very version specific: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85358/what-are-the-guidelines-for-using-version-specific-tags

Comment: Please indent your code so that is valid Python. And please show us a little bit more about what is happening inside `try` and `catch`.

Comment: Also, it would be nice if you wrote entire sentences, including punctuation. Spelling is a bonus.

Comment: If you have a `for` loop, change it to a `while` loop and only increment the `i` value `i += 1` in the `try` block. Also, I'm assuming that your indentation is correct in the actual code.

Comment: now see the above what am i doing. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunatly, there is no simple way to go back with iterator in Python :

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

You should be interested in this stackoverflow's thread :
[Making a python iterator go backwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777188/making-a-python-iterator-go-backwards)

For your particular case, i will use a simple while loop :

```
url = []
i = 0
while i < len(url): #url is list contain all urls which contain infinite as url updates every day
    data = url[i]
    try:
        #getting data from there
        i+=1
    except:
        #shows the error received and continue to next loop i need to make the loop start from same position
```

The problem with the way, you want to handle your problem is that you will risk to go on a infinite loop. For example if a link is broken r = urllib2.urlopen(abc) will always run an exception and you will always stay at the same position. You should consider doing something like that :

```
r = urllib2.urlopen(url) 
encoding = r.info().getparam('charset')
html = r.read()
c = td.find('a')['href']
urls = []
urls.append(c)
#collecting urls from first page then from those url collecting further info in below loop
NUM_TRY = 3
for abc in urls:
   for _ in range(NUM_TRY):
       try:
           r = urllib2.urlopen(abc) 
           encoding = r.info().getparam('charset')
           html = r.read()
           break #if we arrive to this line, it means no error occur so we don't need to retry again
                #this is why we break the inner loop
       except Exception as e:
           last_error = e
           time.sleep(retry_timeout) #here is the problem once get error then switch from next value
```

Comment: hum i don't get the first four line, it look like you forget something like removing the for and some indentation

Comment: The i+=1 is a shortcut for i = i + 1, it the line that will make data = url[i] go to the next element of url.

Comment: @user3387184: Your [code looks similar to this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22479594/4279). All you needed to do is to wrap `for _ in range(max_retries):` block with `for url in urls:` as @Luc shows above